# Un error intermitente (solo a veces)me aparece al ejecutar varias peticiones mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, select

No entiendo mucho de php, pero tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo en un archivo varios SELECTS ( mas de 20 probablemente)  y hasta hace una semana me funcionaba perfectamente. El caso es que ahora, me salta el siguiente error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro\Pagina.php:169
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro\Pagina.php(169): mysqli_fetch_array(false)
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro\Pagina.php</b> on line <b>169</b><br />
```

A veces ocurre el el primer SELECT, otras en el tercero, no es siempre en el mismo sino que va cambiando. Lo peor de todo y que vuelve este problema un completo rompecabezas, es que no salta siempre el error, sino que igual una vez funciona y otra vez salta el error, o funciona dos veces y luego no funciona otras dos. Es decir, es intermitente, algunas veces sale y otras no. Los SELECT son todos iguales lo único que varían son los datos de la tabla y columna.
Aquí dejo tres de ellos:

```
<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE grupo = '".$grupopregun."' ORDER BY RAND()";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $pregunta = $mostrar['preguntas'];
    ?>
    <?php }?>
<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE preguntas = '".$pregunta."' ORDER BY RAND()";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $id = $mostrar['id'];
    ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE id='".$id."' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $respuesta_correcta = $mostrar['respuesta_correcta'];
    ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

He intentado varias cosas pero hay otro problema. Al ser un fatal error, a partir del lugar donde ocurre el error (por ejemplo la línea 169), no compila nada más y no muestra nada más. Lo que elimina muchas posibilidades con las que encontrar cual es el error en concreto. El error que me aparece, lo puedo observar en sources de inspeccionar. El $conn no tiene ningún fallo, ya que es el mismo que uso en otros archivos  y no hay problema. Además, la variable $grupopregun siempre tiene valor por lo que no es el problema, y cuando introduzco eso directamente en la tabla de mysql, siempre me da resultado. Necesito una solución. Muchas gracias. Cualquier posible solución, ayuda, sugerencia e incluso consejos me serían útiles y estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Usa la siguiente instrucción cuando ejecutes la query para ver si tu error viene de la consulta ```$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysqli_error($conn));```

Comment: @rpaillao Me sigue dando el error y no es de la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estamos ante un caso típico de lo que yo llamo *programación ingenua* o *programación optimista*. Es decir, programar pensando que todo es color de rosa y que todo irá bien siempre. Pues hay que caerse del burro: todo no tiene por qué ir bien, **los errores existen** y más aún **una de las tareas principales de un programa debería ser prever los errores, afrontarlos, proporcionar salidas en esos casos**. De modo que deberías ser lo más *pesimista* posible cuando programes. Significa pensar en todos los errores posibles en ese escenario incorporando en una etapa más avanzada del código una política de control de errores.

Dices por ejemplo: *probé la conexión en otro código y funciona, por tanto, la conexión no es el problema*. Eso no puedes saberlo de ningún otro modo que verificando in situ el estado de la conexión. La misma pudo haber funcionado hace un segundo, pero, ¿qué tal si el servidor de la BD se cayó, o un hacker lo atacó o el gato derramó el café sobre el servidor y el mismo se encendió en llamas? Pues sí, hay que pensar lo peor cuando programas, si quieres un código robusto que te diga lo que ha pasado o que sea dirigido a una política de manejo de errores en esos casos...

Por otro lado: ¿por qué tantas consultas sobre lo mismo en tu código? Estamos ante consultas redundantes, en las cuales lees dentro de bucles `while` conjuntos de resultados para quedarte luego con una respuesta correcta tomada de forma aleatoria. Esto podría resolverse con esta consulta simplemente:

```
SELECT respuesta_correcta 
FROM preguntas 
WHERE grupo = '$grupopregun' 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Esto es lo que hacen tus tres consultas con sus tres `while`, según lo que se logra descifrar del código. Si estoy equivocado en esto por favor acláralo en la pregunta o en comentarios...

Para el caso que nos ocupa, sería algo así más o menos (aplicando programación *pesimista* y simplificando). Si por algún motivo debes poner todos esos `while` sin sentido hazlo, verificando siempre el estado de la llamada a `query`, como se hace en el primer `while`. Se trata de controlar todo aquello que pueda fallar:

```
<?php 

    /*
       Variable para controlar el flujo
    */
    $outPut=array();
    
    /*
       1. ¿Hay conexión?
    */
    if ($conn) {
        $sql="SELECT respuesta_correcta FROM preguntas WHERE grupo = '$grupopregun' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        /*
          2. ¿No Falla esta consulta?
        */
        if ( $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) ) {
            /*
               Dado que obtendremos una sola fila
               no es necesario usar while aquí
            */
            $mData=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $outPut['data']=$mData["respuesta_correcta"];
        } else {
            $outPut['error']='Error SQL: '.mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    } else {
        $outPut['error']='No hay conexión';
    }
    /*
       Hacemos un test del resultado final
       Usa $outPut según convenga
       Aquí se balbucea ya 
       una política de manejo de errores
       según la cual "$outPut contendrá una clave 'error'
       cuando algún error ocurra en el flujo del código
     */
    var_dump($outPut);    
?>
```

Cualquier duda, puedes decirlo en comentarios.